# Работа только с одним элементом Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Допустим у меня есть 4 блока div , с одинаковыми классами, как можно по клику спрятать только тот , на который производился клик.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` в обработчиках событий jQuery - это DOM элемент, чье событие обрабатывается.

http://api.jquery.com/on/

> When jQuery calls a handler, the `this` keyword is a reference to the
>   element where the event is being delivered; ...

```
$(".myClass").click(function(){
  $(this).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, это поможет:

https://api.jquery.com/event.target/

С помощью этого метода Вы получите элемент, по которому кликнули, после чего сможете спрятать его.